# How to align labels at the center of arrows when plotting a quiver?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am using tikz to draw some quivers like this one
[image]

However, labeles are not centered and arrows are tilted.

I use the following code

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    k
    \arrow[r, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description]
    \arrow[r, bend left,        "f_1"]
    \arrow[r, bend right, swap, "f_n"]
    &
    k\oplus k
\end{tikzcd}
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the automatic positioning chooses to place the labels `above left`/`below left` instead of just `above`/`below`. Specify the position with e.g. `"f_1"above` and it works fine.

If you also specify the `start anchor` and `end anchor` the arrows look perhaps better. (There might be better ways of doing this, I don't know `tikz-cd` that well.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    k
    \arrow[r, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description]
    \arrow[r, bend left,  start anchor=north east, end anchor=north west, "f_1"above]
    \arrow[r, bend right, start anchor=south east, end anchor=south west, "f_n"below]
    &
    k\oplus k
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a command to rotate arrows?

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you!